# Sanitize/Filter associative elements in user input array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, associative-array, sanitization

I would like to validate that an array has and only has "a", "b", and "c" as associate keys, and that the values are either integers or either NULL or 0 (what ever is easier).

For instance, `array('a'=>123,'b'=>'abc', 'd'=>321)` should be converted to `array('a'=>123,'b'=>0, 'c'=>0)`.

I can do something like the following, but it is a little difficult to read, and will become big if I don't just have 3 elements but 300.

```
$newArr=array(
    'a' => (isset($arr['a'])) ? (int)$arr['a'] : 0,
    'b' => (isset($arr['b'])) ? (int)$arr['b'] : 0,
    'c' => (isset($arr['c'])) ? (int)$arr['c'] : 0
);
```

Another option is something like the following:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach (array('a','b','c') as $key)
{
    $newArr[$key] = (isset($arr[$key])) ? (int)$arr[$key] : 0;
}
```

I guess this works good enough, however, am curious whether there is some slick array converting function that I don't know about that would be better.

Comment: So what you want, is to merge arrays? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: You could use `array_map` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: I think this is a better job for an Object. But if only arrays are used, the second solution seems best to do what you describe.

Comment: @Bondye  How would array_merge() work?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha  The array is being provided via $_POST, so it wouldn't be worthwhile to convert to an object.  Just curious, what did you have in mind?

Comment: @WaleedKhan  Never used array_map() before.  I don't suppose it supports something like a JS anonymous function?  Otherwise, it seems to be more complicated.

Comment: @user1032531 It does. PHP 5.something supports anonymous functions.

Comment: @WaleedKhan  Wow!, Never new that.  I am using PHP5.3.  Just checked the manual regarding anonymous functions.  Guess I have some reading to do.  Think it is a better way to do it?

Comment: There is no slick way. The second option is the best (with minor fixes).

Comment: @SalmanA.  Yep, noticed I was missing a parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to re-write your function using a combination of:

- [`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to remove extra keys
- [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to add missing keys
- [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to change every thing to NULL or integer

However, this only makes it complicated. The slickest way IMO is this:

```
$test = array("a" => 123, "b" => "x", "d" => 123);
$testcopy = array();
foreach (array("a", "b", "c") as $key) {
    $testcopy[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $test)
        ? filter_var($test[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("default" => NULL)))
        : NULL;
}
var_dump($testcopy);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
    ["a"]=> int(123)
    ["b"]=> NULL
    ["c"]=> NULL
}
```

Comment: Don't know if I will do it, but my question was what is the slickest way, and I agree this is the slickest way!

Answer (score 0):

array map is nice http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
$arr = array('a'=>123,'b'=>'abc', 'd'=>321);
function intize($n){return (int)$n;}

$arr = array_map("intize",$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

or for the keys, array_walk

```
$arr = array('a'=>123,'b'=>'abc', 'd'=>321);
function intize(&$n,$key){
    if($key =='a'||$key=='b'||$key=='c')
        $n= (int)$n;
    else
        unset($n);
}

array_walk($arr,"intize");
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: This will ensure they are integers, but not ensure all required keys are present, or whether any extra keys are included.

Comment: I've adjusted to include array_walk now, which should account for the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution...

```
// create array of required keys with default values
$defaultKeys = array('a','b','c');
$defaultVals = array_fill(0, count($defaultKeys), 0); 
$defaults = array_combine($defaultKeys, $defaultVals);

$args = array('a'=>123,'b'=>'abc', 'd'=>321);

// merge arguments with defaults, overwriting default values with arg values and preserving keys
$args = array_merge($defaults, $args);

// remove key/value pairs present in args that don't exist in defaults 
$args = array_intersect_key($args, $defaults);

// filter values, replacing anything that isn't an integer of 0 or greater value with a 0
$args = array_map( function($v) { return (is_integer($v) && $v >= 0) ? $v : 0; }, $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Establish a default/lookup array, then as you iterate it you can compares its keys against the user input and check if qualifying elements have qualifying values.

The two below techniques are "slick", in my opinion, and will make your code easy to maintain because you will only ever need to maintain the default array.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o7cmr))

```
$array = ["a" => 123, "b" => "x", "d" => 123];
$default = ["a" => null, "b" => null, "c" => null];
```

1. Functional style:

   ```
   var_export(
       array_replace(
           $default,
           array_filter(
               array_intersect_key($array, $default),
               'is_int'
           )
       )
   );
   ```
2. Language construct iteration (modify the default array):

   ```
   foreach ($default as $k => &$v) {
       if (isset($array[$k]) && is_int($array[$k])) {
           $default[$k] = $array[$k];
       }
   }
   var_export($default);
   ```